# Radical addition and radical cleavage of cyclohexene and cyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry

> Using reaction mechanism, why radical bromination of cyclohexene is faster than cyclohexane? Draw the stereochemistry of most stable product(s) of both cyclohexene and cyclohexane.

Here are what I get so far

1. I'm not sure about the kinetics of the reaction but I worry the kinetics vs thermodynamics factor (and I can't find any reaction coordinate that can show energy of possible radical position in cyclohexene and cyclohexane in one diagram).
2. Radical bromination of cyclohexene can undergo two competing reactions, radical addition and radical cleavage then followed by SN2 mechanism. I'm not sure if cyclohexane-bromonium ion can be formed in radical addition.
3. Drawing stereochemistry, should I prove it using chair conformation for both cyclohexene or cyclohexane to show the most stable product? I really don't know how to show the bromonium ion on that chair conformation and how SN2 attacks the ion (I thought it should be attack on backside but I can't prove why backside). Maybe some people will just throw "check this reference" but how I even can connect the conformation to resonance-stabilized cyclohexene product.

Can someone help me to connect the dots and what I miss from interpreting the question? Thank you.

Comment: How much does a double bond stabilise a radical in the allyl position?